# Unable to login to GitHub container registry from jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, github, registry

I wrote a jenkins pipeline a while ago to build an image from Dockerfile and push that image to github registry. I logged from the jenkins host via cli already, and execute a shell command to push the image from pipeline

Something like this:

```
git push ghcr.io/owner/image:tag
```

But since this morning I'm facing an issue with pushing image part. At first it was failing with the error `denied:denied`. When I tried debugging it, I created another job just for testing, and tried logging into ghcr first. It said `cannot perform an interactive login from non TTY device`

I'm still able to login, push & pull the images from our private registry with the same credentials (my username and git hub personal token), but when I do it with jenkins job I get the above message.

One more thing I did was, I switched to jenkins user from jenkins host, and tried logging in to github registry with same creds. Now, I get this error: `Error response from daemon: Get https://ghcr.io/v2/: denied: denied`

Can someone please explain what I might have messed up since yesterday? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: GitHub did a revamp of their tokens recently (there was something on the GitHub engineering blog). Existing tokens should continue to work, but maybe try creating a new personal access token and try using that? The timing of your problem and the github token change looks similar enough to be suspicious!

Comment: did you find an answer?